# In gdb, after i press tab, it can complete my command as well as local variable but why lldb can not

Tags: c++, c, lldb

lldb just completes the builtin command but the variable.

It is really awkward but i prefer lldb rather than gdb.
So how can i make lldb work like gdb.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about the `print` (aka `expr`) command here.  gdb uses its own built-in expression parser, so it knows what token your cursor is pointing at when you hit tab, and it can look it up in its symbols list.

lldb uses clang as its expression parser, and getting that to do partial parsing and completion is a more complicated task, and one we haven't gotten to yet.